# How to exclude particular worksheet names from looping?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where I have an Excel workbook in whiche are multiple worksheets.

For example:

```
Main 
Sheet1 
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet4
Sheet5
Sheet6
.
.
.
And so on
```

In Combobox I want to display all worksheet names except these sheet names: `Main`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet5`

Means my combobox should have only below sheet name

```
Sheet1 
Sheet2
sheet4
sheet6
… and so on
```

I have a code which works when I mention only one sheet name: "Main" to be excluded.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()      
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

When I modified and added multiple sheet name code does not work display all sheet names.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Main , Sheet 3, Sheet 5" Then
            Me.ComboBoxpgname.AddItem ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of yourse you need to test each name on its own

```
If ws.Name <> "Main" And ws.Name <> "Sheet 3" And ws.Name <> "Sheet 5" Then
```

otherwise you are testing for *one* sheet that is actually named `Main , Sheet 3, Sheet 5`.

*Make sure to get the worksheet names correcly. In your example some have spaces some not.*

Comment: Upvoted, and just for fun, in this very specific case you could use `Like` operator > `If ws.Name <> "Main" And Not ws.Name Like "Sheet [35]" Then`.

Comment: @JvdV yes, I didn't mention it because I hope the sheet names are only examples. Whoever names his sheets in real life `Sheet 1` to `Sheet 5` should not deserve any friends :(